# How to retrieve a stack trace from the actual stack ?

Tags: c, stack, stack-trace

I am working on a embedded device that uses a stack based on a `frame pointer` and a `stack pointer`. In order to identify an invalid floating point operation, I've set the `floating-point invalid operation` interrupt.

Unfortunately, once in the interrupt, I have no ideas where the exception occurred. Fortunately, I have access to my program's stack memory.

I initially thought I just have to get the last frame pointer minus 1 to get the return value which is true. However, the address I get is the one from the interrupt dispatcher that do the context switch.

What I am looking for is the previous return address two frames before the latest.

The problem is, I don't know the size of each frame.

What solution can I use solve my issue and get the address of the program counter right before the interrupt?

Comment: What embedded platform is your target? What is the compiler? Some compilers have special functions that gets a stack trace.

Comment: Does your platform not have external debugging capabilities?

Comment: It does, unfortunately I am not running my application in debug mode.

Comment: You have to look into the documentation of the controller you are programming for. Typically, the original stack pointer is pushed on the stack right before the exception handler starts.

Comment: Embedded assembler is probably your friend here. Just move the SP to a local variable in the ISR .. then you have access.

Comment: @kdopen Yes I am thinking about modifiying the Analog Devices Interrupt Dispatcher to save the return address in a *global* variable. But, this is dirty solution.

Comment: @nowox This is a dirty problem you're trying to solve. But why modify the dispatcher? It's only in your particular ISR you need this info